# How do I get a shiny reactive data table output, then apply a function to the filtered data?

Tags: r, shiny, aggregate, r-markdown

I'm probably going about this the wrong way entirely, but I could really use some direction on how to do this.

My dataset is a `data.frame` and I have written a reactive script to filter it based on one column when the user clicks the button. The output is a table that I can view when I enter `filtered.data()` after `renderDataTable` in the script below, but what I want is to then apply the `aggregate` function to the output data and view that output.

So in short, I want to filter my data frame, then apply a function to the filtered data, and output the result of that.

An example of what doesn't work:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
# Make a data frame
weight <- c(1,3,4,7,8,9,12)
material <- c("Wood", "Wood", "Steel", "Steel", "Rock", "Rock", "Rock")
df <- data.frame(weight, material)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(

  selectInput("type", "Material:",
              choices = as.character(unique(df$material))),
  actionButton("Filter", "Set Filter"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("filtered.result")

),

#server.r
server = function(input, output) {

  filtered.data <- eventReactive(input$Filter, {
    df %>%
      filter(material == input$type)
  })

  output$filtered.result <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    aggregate(weight~material, filtered.data, mean)
  })
})
```

This gives the error: "cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame" which I understand - I can't apply the `aggregate` function to the output "filtered.data", but is there a way to output the data following the reactive filter that I can apply the `aggregate` function to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use

> observeEvent

So replace server code to

```
server = function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$Filter, {
    output$filtered.result <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
      aggregate(
        weight~material, 
        df %>%
          filter(material == input$type), 
        mean)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Also, selectInput produce event, you can delete your button and change first argument in observeEvent to input$type (or many inputs as "c(input$type1, input$type2)") if you want change results immediately after change input value